# How to accept only Month and Year using DatePicker in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, datepicker

I am building an app using swift and in that app there is one field for accepting expiry date for Debit card for payment purpose. How can I accept only month and year by using DatePicker in Swift.

If it is not possible using datepicker then please suggest any another way.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Choice-1**

**Objective-C**

```
yourDatepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

**Swift**

```
 yourDatepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
```

**Swift3**

```
yourDatepicker.datePickerMode = .date
```

the another modes are

- UIDatePickerModeTime,
- UIDatePickerModeDate,
- UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
- UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer

**Choice-2**

the above method not working well, then check this [link](https://github.com/bendodson/MonthYearPickerView-Swift)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :-)

Comment: @ChetanPurohit --if the first is not hopeful try the second choice , it is very useful for you

Comment: Thanks for your advice Karthik. I will try it.

Comment: Thank you very much dude. That is what I was looking for. i will use the second one.

Comment: @ChetanPurohit -- if my answer is fine give the upvote for the answer, it is useful for future

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but an alternative: why not use a picker for month an a picker for year like most apps do (also on websites the equivalent a popupmenu is used)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. :-)

Comment: This may work for smaller apps, but for apps working in several countries it would be a bad option because of the different calendars countries use.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this link: https://github.com/bendodson/MonthYearPickerView-Swift

It is saving my time to validate valid dates months

```
 let expiryDatePicker = MonthYearPickerView()

private func pickADate() {
    self.invitationTypeTemp = self.expiredDetailOutlet.text ?? "unknown error"

    //FORMAT DATE
   //        expiryDatePicker.datePickerMode = .date

    expiryDatePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    expiryDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "textColor")
    expiryDatePicker.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
    expiryDatePicker.contentMode = .center
    expiryDatePicker.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
    self.view.addSubview(expiryDatePicker)

    toolBar = UIToolbar.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50))
    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(onDoneButtonTappedDateExpired))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(onCancelButtonTappedDateExpired))

    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(toolBar)

    //DISABLE RIGHT ITEM & LEFT ITEM
   //        disableCancelAndSaveItems()

    //DISABLED SELECTION FOR ALL CELLS
   //        ableToSelectCellsAndButtons(isAble: false)

    //DISABLE RIGHT ITEM & LEFT ITEM
    isEnableCancelAndSaveItems(isEnabled: false)

    //SHOW GREY BACK GROUND
    showGreyOutView(isShow: true)
    expiryDatePicker.onDateSelected = { (month: Int, year: Int) in
        let string = String(format: "%02d/%d", month, year)
        self.expiredDetailOutlet.text = string
        NSLog(string) // should show something like 05/2015
    }
}
```