# Error in MonthYearPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I need to implement date picker for expire date only with month and year in swift.  So I follow this thread [How to accept only Month and Year using DatePicker in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580005/how-to-accept-only-month-and-year-using-datepicker-in-ios) and as it suggest I used [MonthYearPickerView-Swift](https://github.com/bendodson/MonthYearPickerView-Swift) in github.

I add that subclass to my application and implement the code as

```
let expiryDatePicker = MonthYearPickerView()
expiryDatePicker.onDateSelected = { (month: Int, year: Int) in
    let string = String(format: "%02d/%d", month, year)
    NSLog(string) // should show something like 05/2015
}
```

But I have an error in first line  as

> Missing argument for parameter 'frame' in call

Can anyone (who used this earlier)help me to solve this? Or any other way to create date picker only for month and year?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line of code exactly is causing the error?

Comment: oops I will edit my question. Actually it's first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is saying that you need to pass the `frame` as argument label with `init`, so you need to call `init(frame:)` and passed `CGRect` instance.

```
let expiryDatePicker = MonthYearPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 170))
```

**Note:** Pass `CGRect` instance according to your view.

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the frame of MonthYearPickerView and add this view to View where you want to have it or see it.

```
let hightOfMonthYearPickerView: CGFloat = 200
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: hightOfMonthYearPickerView)
let expiryDatePicker = MonthYearPickerView()
expiryDatePicker.frame = frame
expiryDatePicker.onDateSelected = { (month: Int, year: Int) in
    let string = String(format: "%02d/%d", month, year)
    print(string) // 05/2015
}
mainView.addSubview(expiryDatePicker)
```